# Handlebars.js & i18n-js, new helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, javascript, handlebars.js

I would like to translate my i18n keys on client side using *Handlebars* and Ruby's *i18n-js* gem (on a Rails 3 app).  According to you, what could be a such Handlebars helper?

According the current Handlebars version, default helpers looks like:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('if', function(context, options) {
  var type = toString.call(context);
  if(type === functionType) { context = context.call(this); }

  if(!context || Handlebars.Utils.isEmpty(context)) {
    return options.inverse(this);
  } else {
    return options.fn(this);
  }
});

Handlebars.registerHelper('unless', function(context, options) {
  var fn = options.fn, inverse = options.inverse;
  options.fn = inverse;
  options.inverse = fn;

  return Handlebars.helpers['if'].call(this, context, options);
});

Handlebars.registerHelper('with', function(context, options) {
  return options.fn(context);
});

Handlebars.registerHelper('log', function(context) {
  Handlebars.log(context);
});
```

About i18n-js gem, it seems to be a nice combinaison.  This lib is for instance used inside Ember.js (as ember-i18n).  Is there already a best practice about Handlebars.js and i18n?

Thank you for any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a handlebars helper with i18n-js. This should suit your needs quite well:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8796912/499700